# How to get the job name and that job uses which database name and the server name from in SQL server query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using the below query to get the jobname and that job depending on which database?

```
SELECT job.job_id,
   NAME,
   description,
   command,
   server,
   database_name FROM   msdb.dbo.sysjobs job
   INNER JOIN msdb.dbo.sysjobsteps steps
           ON job.job_id = steps.job_id WHERE  job.enabled = 1;
```

But the Database names are not accurate and when a job contains XMLA code (partition creation/Cube processing code) the above query not showing correct database name ?

Any suggestions to get the details using SQL Query .

Comment: What do you mean the database names are "wrong"?

Comment: Do you mean the job step is set to one database but the code inside the job step works in another database? How do you know which one is the "correct" database name? What if the job step is set to db1 but has a query that joins sys.objects to db2.sys.tables and db3.sys.schemas? How are you going to determine that db1 is the "wrong" database? And which one could possibly be (more) correct in that case?